# Apache: doing pattern matching and grouping with a RewriteRule leads to the local path instead of getting the URL component

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use RewriteRule's pattern to get the path requested and redirect the client elsewhere keeping the path in the resulting redirect.

I thought something like this would do the trick:

```
RewriteRule.  ^(.*)$ http://testserver/test/$1
```

If the user requests **foo**, send him to **test/foo** (don't worry about looping, I put some RewriteCond logic to prevent that).

To my surprise, Apache ends up with something like http://testserver/foo/var/www/html. What it did was the following:

```
/bar   /var/www/html/bar
```

I raised the log level of mod_rewrite and found out it did the match, but Apache was expand matching the local path of **/**, which is **/var/www/html** and using that to redirect the browser, which won't surely work.

I tried using **[PT]** which I thought would prevent the expansion, but it didn't.

Any idea on how can I prevent it from happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Best

Comment: After modifying the file, I found out that this problem happens when the RewriteRule is inside an **<If>** Apache statement. I've been reading the Apache docs and I saw nothing that'd lead me to think this is the expected behaviour. Any idea?